# Laravel captcha_img() in blade not found 404

Tags: laravel

Today I install package Laravel Captcha (https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha)
But in Blade not working `{!! captcha_img() !!}`.

Register Blade

```
<div class="form-group mb-2">
   <div class="captcha">
       {!! captcha_img() !!}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" class="reload" id="reload">
           &#x21bb;
       </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-2">
   <div class="captcha">
       <input id="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Captcha" name="captcha">
   </div>
</div>
```

Browser show html

[image]

Error in Console

```
GET http://simfind.loc/captcha/default?Ff3XLM4u 404 (Not Found)
```

I don’t understand why the capcher doesn’t show. Any help. (Laravel 8).

Comment: You forget to define route?

Comment: No, this package bad. Im remove this package for captcha and install https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha this package its fine work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package not optimized for Laravel version 8, I remove this package and install https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha google no-captcha. Its fine work! Thanks all.